# Characterization of Reflexive Subspaces of finite signed-measures

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, banach-spaces, reflexive-space, signed-measures

I'm looking for a characterization of the reflexive subspaces of the space of finite measures on a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$.  Maybe something, more informative than the unit ball is compact...

Does any one have a reference?